# How to add toolbar search for specific column in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am having three columns in a jqGrid and i want to add toolbar search on first two only not third one.Here is my code for toolbar search:

```
jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
```

Oh I got the solution:
just apply this for third column **search:false**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: just apply this for third column **search:false**

```
colModel:[          
                    {name:'exGroupName',index:'exGroupName', width:150},
                    {name:'exerName',index:'exerName', width:100},
                    {name:'view',index: 'view', search:false, label: 'view',width:100},
                ],
```